# Is there a way to define a custom back-end for torch.distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I have implemented LLama2-7b-chat set-up through FastAPI and it works just fine but is a little slow (takes 10-20 seconds to respond). I'm investigating ways to squeeze out as much performance as possible before sizing up the hardware

I'd like to try the 'hidet' backend instead of the standard 'nccl' but torch.distributed only supports certain defined backends ('nccl','gloo','mpi').

a custom backend example has been shown using torch.compile but this doesn't seem to work with torch.distributed nor does it seem to work with Llama2 as it's not a torch model (which is what's in the example).

Current code that works (changing backend='nccl' to backend='hidet' doesn't work):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os, subprocess
from pydantic import BaseModel
from llama import Llama
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torchvision
import numpy
import scipy
import tabulate
import time
import hidet

#SET ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'

#SET TORCH PARAMETERS
WORLD_SIZE = 1
WORLD_RANK = 0
backend = 'nccl'

#LAUNCH TORCH PROCESS
dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=WORLD_RANK, world_size=WORLD_SIZE)

#define the llama generator:
generator = Llama.build(ckpt_dir='llama/llama/llama-2-7b-chat/',tokenizer_path='llama/llama/tokenizer.model',max_seq_len=512,max_batch_size=4)

#define the function to get a response from LLAMA-2-7B
def llama_generate_7b(prompt,temperature=0.6,top_p=0.9):
    prompt_formatted = [[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],]
    results = generator.chat_completion(prompt_formatted,temperature=temperature,top_p=top_p,)[0]
    output = f"{results['generation']['content']}"
    return output

#FastAPI Set-up:
class Payload(BaseModel):
    prompt: str


class ResponseSchema(BaseModel):
    description: str

app = FastAPI()


#Method definitions


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "GPU LLM services API is live"}


@app.post("/llama2_7b")
async def llama2_7b(payload: Payload) -> ResponseSchema:
    prompt_in = f'{payload.prompt}'
    start_time = time.time()
    output_description = llama_generate_7b(prompt_in)
    end_time = time.time()
    time_elapsed = (end_time-start_time)
    return ResponseSchema(description= f'{output_description}, elapsed time: {time_elapsed}')


#Launch FastAPI

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, timeout_keep_alive=300, timeout_graceful_shutdown=300)
```